# Expansion of an anti-symmetric tensor with a symmetric tensor

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, symmetry

I am trying to expand these two tensors:

$4H^{[db]c}C_{(dc)}^{\enspace \enspace a}$

As you can see the first tensor is anti-symmetric while the second tensor is symmetric.

My question is; when I expand these two would I get the following result?

$4H^{[db]c}C_{(dc)}^{\enspace \enspace a} \equiv \dfrac{4}{2! 2!} \left[(H^{dbc}-H^{bdc})(C_{dc}^{\enspace \enspace a}+C_{cd}^{\enspace \enspace a}) \right]$.

Or is there possibly some other result, please?

Thanks very much in advance for the assistance and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what exactly you mean by

> ...the first tensor is anti-symmetric while the second tensor is symmetric.

If you mean that the tensors already have those properties, i.e.
$$H^{abc} = H^{[ab]c} \hspace{1cm} \text{and} \hspace{1cm} {C_{ab}}^{c} = {C_{(ab)}}^{c}$$
then you can just *not write* the brackets and parentheses in your product
$$4H^{[db]c}{C_{(dc)}}^{a} = 4H^{dbc}{C_{dc}}^{a}. $$

On the other hand, if your tensors do **not** have those (anti)symmetry properties by themselves, then all you can do is expand the product in the way you did.

$$4H^{[db]c}{C_{(dc)}}^{a} = H^{dbc}{C_{dc}}^{a} + H^{dbc}{C_{cd}}^{a} - H^{bdc}{C_{dc}}^{a} - H^{bdc}{C_{cd}}^{a}$$